# valueの型を指定したオブジェクトからkeyof typeofでkeyのユニオン型を作る

Tags: typescript

valueの型を指定したオブジェクトがあります。

```typescript
export type SingleTextEditorParamList = {
  title: string;
  value: string | undefined;
  onSubmit: (text: string) => Promise<void>;
  note?: React.ReactNode;
};

const SingleTextEditorParams: Record<string, SingleTextEditorParamList> = {
  a: {...省略},
  b: {...省略},
  c: {...省略},
  d: {...省略} 
};
```

SingleTextEditorParamsから`a|b|c|d`の型を作ることは可能でしょうか？

```typescript
type SingleTextEditorParamKeys = keyof typeof SingleTextEditorParams;
```

これだと`string`になってしまいます。

```typescript
const SingleTextEditorParams: {[key: string]: SingleTextEditorParamList} = {省略}
```

これも試しましたが`string | number`になりました。

```typescript
type SingleTextEditorParamKeys = a|b|c|d;

const SingleTextEditorParams: {[key in SingleTextEditorParamKeys]: SingleTextEditorParamList} = {省略}
```

ってすると、キーが増えた時、二箇所にキーを追加するのが冗長なので嫌だなと思いまして。もし方法があったら教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

型アノテーションをつけない `SingleTextEditorParams` (仮に `UntypedSingleTextEditorParams` とします) を先に作り、
`SingleTextEditorParamKeys` は `keyof typeof UntypedSingleTextEditorParams` とするのはいかがですか。

```js
const UntypedSingleTextEditorParams = {
    a: ...,
    b: ...,
    c: ...,
    d: ...,
};

type SingleTextEditorParamKeys =
    keyof typeof UntypedSingleTextEditorParams;

const SingleTextEditorParams
    : Record<SingleTextEditorParamKeys, SingleTextEditorParamList>
    = UntypedSingleTextEditorParams;
```

Comment: 試してみましたがこの方法だとUntypedSingleTextEditorParamsを定義する時のオブジェクトの値の型チェックが効かないですね（よくみたら当たり前ですが）。やっぱりキーは型の宣言とオブジェクトの宣言二箇所に書かないとダメそうですかね。

Comment: @MasamotoMiyata UntypedSingleTextEditorParams を SingleTextEditorParams に束縛するときに型チェック効きませんか?

Answer (score 2):

まず：`Record<string, SingleTextEditorParamList>`は`{[key: string]: SingleTextEditorParamList}`とほとんど一緒です。Recordの意味については[公式ドキュメント](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)が詳しいのでそちらをご覧ください。

---

問題を解決するためには単に`SingleTextEditorParams`の型注釈を外し、`type SingleTextEditorParamKeys = keyof typeof SingleTextEditorParams`を追加すると良いです。現在の`SingleTextEditorParams`は`Record<string, SingleTextEditorParamList>`となっているので、`keyof typeof SingleTextEditorParams`の結果は`string`となります。

Comment: わかりづらくてすいません。そこは記載が漏れていました。型注釈を外せば作れるのは分かっていたのですが、SingleTextEditorParamsの各要素の型チェックが無くなっちゃうので、それを残したまま、キーを2度書かずに済む方法を探していました。@orangecatさんのやり方でいけそうですね。試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

直接的な方法は無いようです。

#### キーの型だけ推論する構文は無い

質問の動作を実現するには、下記のように、プロパティの値の型は明示（`Foo`）しつつ、キーの型は代入するオブジェクトリテラルから推論する、という構文が必要です。

```js
const fooRec: Record<ここを推論, Foo> = {
    a: { prop: "string" },
    b: { prop: "string" },
    c: { prop: "string" },
}
```

しかし、このような構文はありません。issue にて要望はいくつか出されています。

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45139

#### ジェネリック関数の呼び出しを利用する方法

代替案として、既存の回答にあるように、型を記述せずにすべて推論させる方法があります。この場合、型チェックは変数の使用時に行われるので、エラーが出る箇所などが少し理想と異なります。

できるだけオブジェクトリテラルを書く場所で型チェックを行ないたい場合は、ジェネリック関数の呼び出しを利用する方法があります。ジェネリック関数の呼び出しでは、引数の型チェックを行いつつ、ジェネリック部は推論させることができるので、都合がよいです。

例:

```js
type Foo = {
    prop: string
}

// Record のキーの型を T とし、呼び出し箇所で推論する
function initFooRec<T extends string>(x: Record<T, Foo>): Record<T, Foo> {
    return x
}

// fooRec は Record<"a" | "b" | "c", Foo>
const fooRec = initFooRec({
    a: { prop: "string" },
    b: { prop: "string" },
    c: { prop: "string" },

    // 下のように Foo 型ではない値を入れると、エラーとして検出できる
    // d: { prop: "string", x: 123 },
})

// FooRecKeys は  "a" | "b" | "c"
type FooRecKeys = keyof typeof fooRec
```

キーの型を推論するのに使う `initFooRec` は引数をそのまま返すだけの恒等関数としています。実行時の処理があるならば加えてもよいでしょう。